# Nativescript: The storage Uri could not be parsed

Tags: firebase, nativescript, firebase-storage, angular2-nativescript

I'm building an app using Nativescript and I'm almost new. I'm trying to upload an image with firebase and I use the plugin nativescript-imagepicker for it.

Once I have the images I want then I have to Upload it to Firebase, but when I do it I get the following error:
 **The storage Uri could not be parsed**.

This is my code. See that first I call the function selectImages to select the images that I want from my device, and afterwards for each one I call the function uploadFile, but here is where I have the error.

```
onSelectMultipleTap() {
    // console.log('Im in');



    function selectImages() {
        var context = imagepicker.create({
            mode: "multiple"
        });

        context
            .authorize()
            .then(function() {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(function(selection) {

                selection.forEach(function(selected) {

                    uploadFile(selected);

                });
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }); 
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {

        // init the file-system module
        var fs = require("file-system");

        // grab a reference to the app folder
        var appPath = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path;

        // determine the path to a file in the app/res folder
        var logoPath = appPath + "/res/telerik-logo.png";            

        // now upload the file with either of the options below:
        firebase.uploadFile({

            // optional, can also be passed during init() as 'storageBucket' param so we can cache it (find it in the Firebase console)

            bucket: 'mystory-2.appspot.com',
            // the full path of the file in your Firebase storage (folders will be created)

            remoteFullPath: 'uploads/images/telerik-logo-uploaded.png',
            // option 1: a file-system module File object
            localFile: fs.File.fromPath(logoPath),

            // option 2: a full file path (ignored if 'localFile' is set)
            localFullPath: logoPath,

            // get notified of file upload progress
            onProgress: function(status) {
            console.log("Uploaded fraction: " + status.fractionCompleted);
            console.log("Percentage complete: " + status.percentageCompleted);
            }
        }).then(
            function (uploadedFile) {
                console.log("File uploaded: " + JSON.stringify(uploadedFile));
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("File upload error: " + error);
            }
        );

    }


    selectImages()

}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: seems to be a bug

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/17